# If $P (A) <P (B)$ then $A\subseteq B$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The information I have is: $$P (A) = 3/8$$ $$P (B) = 1/2$$ $$P (A\cap B) = 1/4$$ And I have to calculate:

1. $P ( A^c )=5/8$
2. $P ( B^c )=1/2$
3. $P ( A \cup B )=5/8$
4. $P ( A^c\cap B^c )=3/8$
5. $P ( A^c\cap B )=1/8?$

**So, my question is about $(5)$. It is ok to say that If $P (A) <P (B)\Rightarrow A\subseteq B$?**

**My calculation is $P ( A^c \cap B )=P(B-A)=P(B)-P(A)$. But $P (A)\neq P(A\cap B)$ , so it's mean that $A\nsubseteq B$?**

**How I can calculate it?**

Comment: Nope: $A\subset B~\implies~\mathsf P(A)\leq \mathsf P(B)$, but the converse cannot be assured.

Comment: That is one of the answers I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 
$$\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B \cap A) + \mathbb{P}(B \cap A^c)\text{.}$$

Comment: Does not address question in title.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following setup:

> $$\begin{cases} \Omega = \{1,2\} \\
> P(\{1\}) = 1/3 \\
> P(\{2\}) = 2/3
> \end{cases}$$

Let $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Clearly there is no inclusion despite inequality of probability.

In fact, in general let $A$ be an event with $P(A)<1/2$ Then with $B=A^c$ we have

> $$P(B)>1/2>P(A)$$

and clearly there is no inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cap B = A$ so you would have $P(A) = P(A\cap B)$ which is not true in your case.

If $P(A)<P(B),$ in general you can say little about $A$ and $B$'s inclusion relationship. They can even be disjoint provided $P(A)+P(B) <1.$